# Simple if condition that does not work as expected

Tags: shell, unix

I am new to shell scripting. I am backing up a database and I am trying to have only the recent 8 copies on the server. The following `if` condition always remains false despite the fact that I only have 4 files in that folder.

```
numberOfFiles=$(ls | wc -l)

if [$numberOfFiles -le 9]
then
echo $numberOfFiles
exit 0
fi

ls -t | sed -e '1,8d' | xargs -d '\n' rm
```

How will I modify the if condition and exit the script if the number of files is less than 9 in that folder?

Comment: This line `if [$numberOfFiles -le 9]` needs more spaces. `[` is a command not just syntax. It also requires that `]` be the last argument to the command. So you need `if [ $numberOfFiles -le 9 ]`

Comment: @EtanReisner That was the error over there. Thanks. That worked.

Comment: @EtanReisner Please give that as an answer so that I can accept the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
if [$numberOfFiles -le 9]
```

needs more spaces.

`[` is a command not just syntax. It requires that `]` be the last argument given to it, so you need

```
 if [ $numberOfFiles -le 9 ]
```

instead.